# Two mice, two separate settings on mac

Tags: macos, mouse, touchpad

Is it possible to have separate settings (tracking speed, scrolling speed etc...) for each individual pointing device on OS X?

In system preferences there are separate settings for mice and trackpads, but if have two mice they will work exactly the same, while i want them to have different tracking speeds for different purposes (same for trackpads).

The devices I'm using are (build-in trackpad vs magic trackpad 2) and (magic mouse 1 vs magic mouse 1).

I was hoping to find some kind of .plist that stores their settings but even if i do, i am afraid that two mice share the same configuration file.

Comment: I would guess that you're right (it can't be done), but it's a good question, and maybe someone will know a way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Steer Mouse](http://plentycom.jp/payment/en/purchase/index?APP_NAME=SteerMouse5).

It let's you remap buttons, adjust cursor speed, and more, for each of your pointing devices separately. It's $19.99 and it has a trial version.

Comment: It does not support the Apple Magic Mouse and Magic Trackpad. (according to the website you provided) but regardless it's worth a try

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences>Trackpad (Row 2, 3rd from right)>"Point & Click">Tracking Speed

Changing from slow to fast Tracking on the trackpad via this setting more or less is adjusting DPI on a mouse, higher dpi matching faster tracking, and vice versa.

Bottom right corner of this window too, however, has a button for "Set Up Bluetooth Trackpad".  Although I do not possess one myself, I would guess tracking speed can be adjusted for the second device as well.  Best of Luck!

If nothing else, at least you can adjust one to match the other, but hopefully synchronise both through titration and tinkering.

I use a 5600dpi Logitech mouse plus the late-2015 trackpad on El Cap 10.11.6 and can adjust the two input device's sensitivities individually, but I cannot speak for the bluetooth, unfortunately.